# Android module: Log.{v, d} output are not shown in logcat, bot Log.{w, e} are

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I'm testing an application that uses a module. This module is also compiled when building the application. In the application I see the output of Log.v or Log.d calls, but I do not see these messages when Log.{v,d} is called from the module (I do see the error or warning logs).

I assume I need to compile the module using some debugging options, but I do cannot find information on how to enable this from Gradle/Android Studio.

What do I need to modify?